# Any way to create a simple timeline with Google Charts?

Tags: google-api, google-visualization

Is there any way to create a simple timeline of events with Google Charts? (I don't mean an annotated timeline.)

In my case, I'd like to display a series of event times (not time intervals) in milliseconds, with labels, a bit like this:

```
| eventFoo
  | eventBar
        | eventFooBar

'            '            '
0           500         1000
```

I can think of ways to hack this, for example:

http://www.designinginteractive.com/code/how-to-build-a-gantt-chart-with-the-google-charts-api/

...but it would be nice to be able to code something like this 'natively'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK -- FWIW, I wound up building a JavaScript timeline implementation myself.

You can [see it in action](https://samdutton.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/chrome-extension-to-test-navigation-and-page-load-speed/) in an article I wrote about the Navigation Timing API (at the bottom of the page).

The x-axis in this case displays milliseconds, but the timeline could easily be adapted for dates. Adding tick marks to the x-axis would be somewhat complex algorithmically, but not difficult to code.

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up! I wrote this answer 10.5 years ago :). I've fixed the link.

Comment: What I was after is an example of how to get a Google timeline chart x-axis to display in milliseconds only - no dates please.

Comment: Could you just use a Line Chart with milliseconds on the X axis? https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart