# Plot my own data as a timeline in Google Chrome

Tags: css, user-interface, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to plot my data in the timeline plot as in google chrome's developer tools?

[image]

I have a list of things that happen sequentially in time (ms) like this:

```
   300    333    367    400    402 
   433    467    500    533    536 
   566    600    633    666    669 
   700    733    766    799    802 
   833    866    907    933    943 
   966    999   1033   1066   1076 
  1099   1132   1166   1199   1210 
  1232   1266   1299   1332   1343 
  ...
```

The first 4 columns are times when cameras acquire images,
the last column indicates, when a motor starts moving.

I am aware of this answer, where someone implemented something similar:

[Any way to create a simple timeline with Google Charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346986/any-way-to-create-a-simple-timeline-with-google-charts)

But it doesn't look as nice.

**Has anyone inspected Google's timeline drawing HTML and CSS code and extracted it into a standalone template, that I could easily use to draw my plots into (static) HTML5?**

Answer (score 1):

[jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/index.php) isn't a bad solution, which achieves this exact sort of plot graph.  This question is tagged with "css," this solution uses pure javascript without a lot of load tax.